# Como desfaço o último commit no Git?

Tags: git, versionamento

Sem querer fiz o commit dos arquivos errados para o Git.

Como desfazer isso?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`Reset` so é recomendado se o último commit ainda não tiver sido enviado ("pushed") para o servidor. Caso contrário, desfazer o último commit irá invalidar a copia local.

Se já tiver feito push, o melhor é "reverter" o ultimo commit, em vez de o desfazer.
"Reverter", neste contexto, significa criar um commit novo que apague as linhas introduzidas/introduza as linhas apagadas no último commit.

`git revert HEAD~1`

Ou `HEAD~2` para reverter os 2 últimos commits.

Fonte: [Git revert manpage](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-revert.html).

---

Caso o commit **não** tenha sido publicado, pode-se desfazer o último commit atraves do comando `git reset` - [ver resposta do @paulomartinhago](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3034/2360).

Comment: Obrigado por complementar dcastro :)

Comment: Que tal editar esta resposta para incluir o conteúdo das demais e ficar mais completa? Facilitaria a vida do leitor futuro...

Comment: @ThiagoArrais boa ideia! Adicionei a opcao do `reset` e os devidos creditos ao @paulomartinhago

Comment: Só não sei se Stackoverflow-mente seria mais indicado fazer isso que você fez, editar a resposta do @paulomartinhago ou editar sua resposta como se tu tiveste feito originalmente o conteúdo incluindo a história do reset. Vou abrir uma pergunta lá no meta...

Comment: @ThiagoArrais Eu fiz questao de deixar claro que a historia do reset e' da autoria do paulo, mas tambem nao sei qual e' a melhor opcao.. Podes por aqui o link para a pergunta do meta? Obrigado

Comment: Comentem lá para o pessoal da admin entender a situação. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/644/o-que-e-aceitavel-ou-recomendado-ao-editar-uma-resposta-para-incluir-conteudo-de

Comment: @ThiagoArrais decidi apagar a parte do `reset`, e deixar apenas o link para a resposta do @paulomartinhago ;) parece mais justo

Answer (score 46):

Da pra fazer da seguinte forma quando você elimina as atividades feitas no stage:

```
git reset HEAD~1 --hard
```

ou para voltar com as atividades ao stage:

```
git reset HEAD~1 --soft
```

Answer (score 11):

Após corrigir os arquivos execute um

`git add`

e depois faça:

`git commit --amend`

Na verdade esse comando irá refazer o último commit

Answer (score 8):

Você pode usar esse comando:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

Answer (score 1):

Caso o commit que deseja ser desfeito for um merge terá de usar o --hard.

```
git reset HEAD~1 --hard
```

E caso o commit esteja no origin precisa realizar o push com force:

```
git push -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Caso seu último commit seja o primeiro **(initial commit)** execute o comando  `git update-ref -d HEAD` para recuperar as mudanças da sua arvore de trabalho e assim executar um novo commit

Answer (score -1):

Para desfazer um commit que ainda não foi enviado com `git push` basta executar o comando abaixo:

`git reset --soft HEAD~1`

Lembrando que esse comando só afeta o histórico local.

Answer (score -2):

Além do git revert, é possível usar o hash do commit anterior para voltar a versão.

Por exemplo:

Dando um git log, você verá os últimos commits realizados e um hash identificador do mesmo. Veja:

```
commit c67f03af1701f5c8e47319ae5ad6fc7a2a38151f
Author: Nome <user@server>
Date:   Thu Jan 30 10:50:18 2014 -0200

Debugando
```

Logo, você terá que identificar na lista, o commit anterior ao que você deseja desfazer. Então, basta dar um git checkout:

```
git checkout c67f03af1701f5c8e47319ae5ad6fc7a2a38151f
```

Comment: Isso nao responde a' pergunta: fazer checkout de um commit anterior, nao vai desfazer o commit mais recente.

Comment: Alem disso, se fizer checkout de um commit anterior, e depois fizer um novo commit, vai ficar com uma `detached head`. Isto significa que qualquer commit feito nao ira' pertencer a nenhum branch.

Comment: Hum... não tinha pensado nisso.