# Como remover um commit antigo

Tags: git

Estou tentando remover do meu repositório um commit bem antigo que era só para testar o git, pesquisei algumas soluções e cheguei nisto:

```
git rebase --onto (sha1) (sha2)
```

ou

```
git rebase --onto HEAD~2 HEAD~1
```

Porém recebo alguns erros, a minha dúvida é se existe algum tipo de "padrão" para remover um commit especifico.

Comment: Pensei que os dois fossem o mesmo comando, só que com tipos de instruções diferentes, no caso quais erros você recebe em cada um dos comando?

Comment: Ah ele dá uns erros de conflito, acho que os arquivos do commit antigo nem existem mais, mas no caso da pergunta eu queria saber se esse é o método mais usual para excluir um commit

Comment: Então, como eu disse, até aonde sei ambos comandos são o mesmo, só diferencia pelo tipo de instrução que você passou para identificar, o primeiro acho que é `safe` e o outro é normal, mas a instrução é a mesma.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NOTA: se o commit foi publicado, e o repositorio é usado por outras pessoas, é altamente recomendavel NÃO apagar o commit. Em vez disso, pode "reverter" o commit com o comando "git revert" ([ver esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3038/2360)).

---

O padrão para apagar ou editar um commit antigo é usando um rebase interactivo.

Por exemplo, se quiser apagar o commit com hash 1ca0fcd:

```
git rebase -i 1ca0fcd~1
```

Este comando vai abrir o VIM com a lista de commits após 1ca0fcd (inclusive).
Exemplo de um repositorio meu:

```
pick 1ca0fcd Exposed HttpClient and JsonSerializerSettings through the IJSendClient interface
pick a65278f Updated README to mention CompositeMessageInterceptor
pick cec16d6 Released version 0.3.0
pick 3cdea37 Added link to release notes to nuspecs
pick c862a21 Changed IJSendParser and DefaultJSendParser to use JsonSerializerSettings

# Rebase ddc2139..c862a21 onto ddc2139
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
```

Para apagar um commit, basta apagar a linha desse commit (como indicado nas instruções - "If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST"). Depois escreve `:wq` para gravar e sair do VIM, e o rebase interactivo vai:

- apagar o commit 1ca0fcd e todos os commits após 1ca0fcd
- re-escrever todos os commits após 1ca0fcd

É possivel que ao re-escrever os commits ocorram conflitos. Nesse caso o rebase vai pausar, pedir que resolvas os conflitos, e depois continues usando `git rebase --continue`.

Ler mais: [7.6 Git Tools - Rewriting History](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)

Comment: bem mais simples do que eu imaginava

Comment: Não consegui apagar a linha pelo vim, o cursor passou pela linha inteira e não removeu nada, o que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei uma explicação que acredito que possa te ajudar, porém não pude testar, recomendo que você crie um repositório com branchs e realize um teste, pois são comandos que deve-se ter muito cuidado para executá-los.

1- Dê um checkout no commit anterior ao que você deseja excluir (para localizar o commit você pode usar o git log por exemplo):

```
Ex: git checkout b3d92c5
```

2- Crie um branch novo:

```
Ex: git checkout -b reparo
```

3- Use o comando cherry-pick passando o commit que você deseja excluir:

```
Ex: git cherry-pick 77b9b82
```

4- Volte para o branch master

```
Ex: git checkout master
```

5- Aponte/Reset o master para o último commit

```
Ex: git reset --hard b3d92c5
```

6- Realize um merge com o branch reparo criado anteriormente

```
Ex: git merge reparo
```

7- Dê um push do master para o repositório remoto

```
Ex: git push --hard origin master
```

[Fonte(inglês) com exemplos e maiores detalhes](http://www.clock.co.uk/blog/deleting-a-git-commit)