# Quais as diferenças entre "checkout, revert e reset"

Tags: git

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre os comandos abaixo:

```
git revert commit ;
git reset --hard commit ; 
git checkout commit ;
```

Comment: Sobre o reset, já tem [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/325951/112052)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bem, vou tentar descrever como conheço e utilizo, pois informações macros, você encontra diversas por aí, afinal o GIT é extremamente utilizado.

- **revert** - Ele faz o rollback do commit informado, basicamente um ctrl+z, imagina que você fez o commit X e percebeu que quebrou a
  aplicação, na maior urgência você precisa voltar como estava antes,
  você faz um revert do commit X, porém as vezes que usei, ele deixa
  isso explicito, gerando um novo commit quanto a esse revert, portanto
  ele constará em seu histórico.
- **reset** - A ideia dele é exatamente essa, retornar para um estado anterior, porém diferente do revert, ele não gera commit, ele desfaz
  tudo mesmo, nunca usei ele enviando para o servidor (nem sei se rola), mas as vezes que
  commitei na master por engano, fiz o reset informando o último commit
  válido da master, com isso ele restaurou a master e simplesmente
  eliminou meus commits incorretos
- **checkout** - Esse cara vai para uma branch, tag, commit etc... Ele pode mudar completamente o estado dos seus fontes, imagina que você
  já está no commit 100, porém alguém relata um problema que ocorria no
  commit 50, você consegue voltar para esse commit com o checkout.
  Utilizo dele principalmente para mudar de branch, entre master,
  inovação (RC) e versão atual da aplicação. Também utilizo o git checkout  para desfazer algo que ainda não fiz o commit, tipo git checkout app.js, ele descarta tudo que fiz e ainda não fiz o commit ou o git add.

Recomendo você criar um repositório em algum git free e brincar com esses comandos.

Além da pergunta que o hkotsubo citou, tem essa aqui que está bem legal:
[Como desfaço o último commit no git?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3030/como-desfa%C3%A7o-o-%C3%BAltimo-commit-no-git)

Comment: Muito obrigado, acho que esclareceu minhas duvidas !